# Print a specific field in Python 3 with open

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as list:
    content = list.read()
    rows = content.split("\n")
    for row in rows:
        infos = row.split(' ')
        print(infos)
```

That returns me these values:

```
['2', '064328796150', 'eni-4bad5a20', '172.18.0.124', '172.18.0.5', '3306', '39064', '6', '14', '4123', '1504618064', '1504618121', 'ACCEPT', 'OK']
['2', '064328796150', 'eni-4bad5a20', '172.18.0.124', '172.18.0.5', '3306', '62717', '6', '16', '5981', '1504618064', '1504618121', 'ACCEPT', 'OK']
['2', '064328796150', 'eni-4bad5a20', '172.18.0.5', '172.18.0.124', '52909', '3306', '6', '37', '7112', '1504618064', '1504618121', 'ACCEPT', 'OK']
```

I want to get only the values from fields 1 and 4, for example. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to say "as list" since "list" is a Python built-in (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list) and this clobbers it. "as list_file" might be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to do this as the following:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as f:
    print([[x.split()[0], x.split()[3]] for x in f])
```

or if you want to print each line separately:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as f:
    for line in [[x.split()[0], x.split()[3]] for x in f]:
        print(line)
```

Comment: All right, this example worked fine!  Thank you, and all others.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Just another doubt about this code, I didn't now if I put it here would be the best way, so I openned another topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064932/compare-a-x-splitfield-with-some-values?noredirect=1#comment79090665_46064932

Comment: @Adiel I answered your other question

Answer (score 2):

Because python is 0-indexed:

```
row = row.split(' ')
infos = row[0], row[3]
```

But you also may have to store the `infos` to a list to access later

Answer (score 1):

[`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) could offer an elegant solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter
ig = itemgetter(0,3)

with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as list:
    content = list.read()
    rows = content.split("\n")
    for row in rows:
        infos = row.split(' ')
        relevant_infos=ig(infos)
        print(relevant_infos)
```

Comment: Good idea, except you are not using the itemgetter correctly

Comment: @JBernardo care to elaborate what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try the code, by any chance? Hint: ig(0, 3), should be ig(the_list)

Comment: @JBernardo yikes! I hacked up a list to play with `itemgetter`, and then mucked up the answer when I converted it back to the OP's problem. Thanks for noticing and pointed that out! (edited and fixed)

Comment: That's good, but I got this error on the end of the result:                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adiel/print-log-itemgetter.py", line 9, in <module>
    relevant_infos=ig(infos)
IndexError: list index out of range