# Compare a x.split()[field] with some values

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as f:

    for line in [[x.split()[3], x.split()[4], x.split()[5], x.split()[6]] for x in f]:
        print(line)
```

It works fine, and print these values for me:

```
['172.18.0.124', '172.18.0.5', '3306', '39064']
['172.18.0.124', '172.18.0.5', '3306', '62717']
['172.18.0.5', '172.18.0.124', '52909', '3306']
['172.18.0.5', '172.18.0.124', '13989', '3306']
```

But I want to compare the `x.split()[5]` with some values like `443` or `65535`, and only if it matches them, print the lines.
        How can I make this? 
        Thank's

Comment: Uh-huh... `[x.split()[3], x.split()[4], x.split()[5], x.split()[6]]` is `x.split()[3:7]`, no?

Comment: `if line[2] == <some_value>: print(line)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner and forgot, but, done:                                             for line in [[x.split()[3:7]] for x in f]:

Comment: I want to compare just the field 5 from every lines with 443 or 65535 and only if it matches these values, print the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generator with the splits then print the filtered values:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as f:
    iter_lines = (x.split() for x in f)
    for line in (x[3:7] for x in iter_lines if x[5] in {'443', '65535'}):
        print(line)
```

Or use a for loop to `split()` the lines and print if the condition is met:

```
with open('/home/adiel/log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if line[5] in {'443', '65535'}:
            print(line[3:7])
```

Comment: Why not generate the entire expression through? `for line in (x[3:7] for x in iter_lines if x[5] in LOOKUP_VALUES`

Comment: Thanks all you! The Moe's solution worked perfect for me.